Why don't I see the image in my "Border"?
I'm making a legend inside an XAML file, and I'm using a Border to show what it all looks like. I have three such objects:
<Border x:Name="box_Interior_PalletGroup_Color" Height="20" Width="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Product.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/All_Colours.png" />
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>

<Border x:Name="box_Interior_Brown" Height="20" Width="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Brown"/>

<Border x:Name="box_Interior_Transparant" Height="20" Width="20" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Product.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/Transparant.png" />
    </Border.BorderBrush>
</Border>

The images All_Colours.png and Transparant.png have been imported, using the resource editor.
A screenshot concerning All_Colours.png looks as follows:

In the "Properties" window, you can clearly see the All_Colours.png in the BorderBrush property, but in the XAML, there's nothing.
What should I do in order to see the mentioned files All_Colours.png and Transparant.png in the design of my XAML?
By the way, my "Transparant.png" file looks as follows (a mixture of white and grey squares):

If anybody has a better way to show some "transparant", don't hesitate to let me know.

After some searching, I found the answer to be ridiculously easy, as you can see:
<Border x:Name="box_Interior_PalletGroup_Color" ...>
  <Image Source="/Product.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/Colours.png" />
</Border>

<Border x:Name="box_Interior_Transparant" ...>
  <Image Source="/Product.Customer.Client;component/Views/views/Transp.png" />
</Border>


i suggest not to use an image for the transparency but rather a path. It jjust scales better:
<Grid Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Background="White">
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="gray"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>


Edit:
More colors:
<Grid Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Background="HotPink">
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="Lime"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>


even more colors:
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid Background="HotPink">
        <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="Lime"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Blue">
        <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="Red"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="Green"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Orange">
        <Path Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10 0,10Z M10,10 L20,10 20,20 10,20Z" Fill="Salmon"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>



Is there a way to use this system for showing a whole bunch of colours (not just two types of grey)?

did you try modifying the color in the XAML?
You can bind them to a property and change them on the fly without having 500 image resources in your program

You talk about more colours, but you end up with just two. Is there a way to make such a "carpet" with ±4x4 squares, all of them having their own colour?

can you show a picture of what you want to achive?

cant you just use 5 of these in different colors?
I am confused what you want to do

What I want to do, is simply show an image. (The fact that the image should contain a bunch of squares is just background history)
